# How to check time is in which timezone in swift?

Tags: swift, time, timezone

I am displaying the current time using this code:

```
let UTCDate = Date()
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a"
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier:"GMT")
let defaultTimeZoneStr = formatter.string(from: UTCDate)
```

Can someone help me to check if this time is in which timezone(eg:central timezone, eastern timezone)....

Comment: Your question is unclear. Give an example of what you are trying to determine. BTW - you specifically wrote code to give you a string with the current time in the GMT timezone.

Comment: Yes i wanted a string value...Is it posssible to check if the GMT or local time belongs to particular timezone?

Comment: That makes no sense. If I tell you that it is "2:00 pm", there is no timezone information from that little piece of information. It could be 2:00pm anywhere in the world. Again, what are you actually trying to do (and I don't mean with the code you posted, but in English).

Comment: Is there a way to check the local time with which timezone it belongs to?

Comment: Again, it makes no sense to try to determine a timezone by looking at the local time. If you want to know the user's current timezone, then look at the user's current timezone. You don't need a date or a date formatter, or a string to determine the user's timezone.

Comment: You specifically asked for GMT, so you are seeing the time in GMT.  You can think of GMT as a time zone in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless the time is specified as a string with some kind of time zone indicator, such as "2017-04-14 10:00:00 EDT" or "2017-04-14 10:00:00 -0400", there's no way to tell what time zone for a given time value.

The Swift way to store times as `Date` values, which simply specify a number of seconds before or after January 1, 2001, UTC, and to display any time value using the calendar and time zone that makes the most sense for the user. Usually, this means using the time zone settings, because in *most* cases -- but not *all* cases -- that time zone setting will match the time zone where the user is.

If you want the abbreviated name of the user's current time zone setting, use this:

```
Calendar.current.timeZone.abbreviation()! // returns "EDT" for me;
                                          // I’m in the eastern time zone
                                          // and on daylight saving time
```

Or if you prefer getting the time zone by geographic identifier, use this:

```
Calendar.current.timeZone.identifier // returns "America/New_York" for me
```

Or if you want the full name of the time zone, try this (and play with the parameters):

```
// Returns "Eastern Standard Time" for me
Calendar.current.timeZone.localizedName(for: .standard, locale: Locale.current)
```